# Resampling between raster objects with multiple variables (columns)

Tags: r

I am trying to create a bilinear interpolation from a raster dataset (REF) with 2.5° x 2.5° resolution (5760 coordinates - rows) to another raster dataset (OBS) with 0.5° x 0.5° resolution (61143 coordinates - rows).

Each dataset contains daily temperatures for 27 years across the columns (9862 columns in total).

```
REF    Large SpatialPixelsDataFrame (5760 elements, 435.1 Mb)
 ..@ data :'data.frame': 5760 obs. of 9862 variables
 ...... ..$ 1979.01.01.: num [1:5760] -0.568 -0.166 -0.172 ...
 ...... ..$ 1979.01.02.: num [1:5760] -1.606 -0.915 -0.702 ...
 ...... ..$ 1979.01.03.: num [1:5760] -0.856 -0.037 -0.339 ...

OBS    Large SpatialPixelsDataFrame (61143 elements, 4.5 Gb)
 ..@ data :'data.frame': 61143 obs. of 9862 variables
 ...... ..$ 1979.01.01.: num [1:61143] -10.4 -10.6 -10.7 ...
 ...... ..$ 1979.01.02.: num [1:61143] -7.76 -7.99 -8.25 ...
 ...... ..$ 1979.01.03.: num [1:61143] -7.35 -7.52 -7.72 ...
```

I have tried the following:

```
coordinates(OBS) = ~ X.x. + X.y.
gridded(OBS) = TRUE
OBS.R = raster(OBS)

coordinates(REF) = ~ X.x. + X.y.
gridded(REF) = TRUE
REF.R = raster(REF)

RS = resample(REF.R, OBS.R, method = "bilinear")
```

This produces the desired output, but only for the first variable (i.e. the first day of the 9862 day record). How can I adapt the above to produce an interpolated raster dataset for the whole 27 year record?

Answer (score 0):

This part should not be necessary if you already have SpatialPixels* objects.

```
#coordinates(REF) = ~ X.x. + X.y.
#gridded(REF) = TRUE
```

I do wonder how you got them (that is, if they are from file, it could be an unnecessary intermediate step)

Anyway, you need to use `brick` rather than `raster` to get all layers

```
OBS.R <- brick(OBS)
REF.R <- brick(REF)
RS <- resample(REF.R, OBS.R, method = "bilinear")
```

Comment: Many thanks @Robert Hijmans - a simple change that should make all the difference. I’ve set that to run and it’s still going after almost an hour now, but I guess it’s just a huge dataset. I assume there is no faster way?